# Missing boost::in_place in 1.59

Tags: boost

I upgraded Boost from *1.56* to *1.59* and I can no longer locate `boost::in_place`. According to the `optional` docs it should still be there, but even a grep on the source did not find it.

Could someone point out whether it was removed or in which header it was moved to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still there, but you need to `#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>` to declare it now (that's no longer included by the optional headers).

You can use the `optional::emplace` function instead though, which provides the same functionality without using `in_place`.

Comment: And for initialization of a `optional` member?

Comment: If you still need to use `in_place` then just `#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>` and use it.

Comment: Tried that and it would still not find `in_place`. I get the feeling like usage of `in_place` is by now discouraged and thus will stay clear of it.

Comment: It works fine for me with Boost 1.59.0, see http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/m0JX9VBFC5i3pICH